# How do you pass a function pointer to a function in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include "stdio.h"
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
int withFive(int x, int (*func))
{
    return (*func)(x,5);
}
int main()
{
    void (*funcptr)(int) = &add;
    printf("%d", withFive(10,funcptr));
    return 0;
}
```

This code seems like it would compile based on my understanding of function pointers but there is an error that a function or function pointer isn't being passed to `withFive`. How should I write `withFive` so that the compiler will accept the argument as a function ptr?

Comment: Most likely the downvote on your question is for paraphrasing your error. If you copy and paste the actual error (use the edit button) it will make it a better question.

Answer (score 2):

The definition should be

```
int withFive(int x, int (*func)(int, int ) )
```

or

```
int withFive(int x, int (*func)(int x, int y) )
```

like in a variable definition.

Btw:  `void (*funcptr)(int) = &add;` should be `int (*funcptr)(int,int) = &add;` as well or just `int (*funcptr)(int,int) = add;`

Answer (score 2):

```
int withFive(int x, int (*func))
```

You want, as an argument, a function `func` that returns `int` *and takes two `int` as parameter*.

So you need:

```
int withFive(int x, int (*func)(int, int))
```

Then:

```
{
    return (*func)(x,5);
}
```

You don't need to dereference `func`. Just write

```
return func(x, 5);
```

Then:

```
void (*funcptr)(int) = &add;
```

That's the wrong type again. And you don't need to take the address of `add`. Just write:

```
int (*funcptr)(int, int) = add;
```

Or you could just write:

```
printf("%d", withFive(10,add));
```

Generally speaking, to make handling the somewhat awkward function pointer syntax easier and the result more readable, you could use a `typedef`. All together, and some other minor edits included:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*binary_func_t)( int, int );

int add( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int withFive( int x, binary_func_t func )
{
    return func( x, 5 );
}

int main()
{
    printf( "%d\n", withFive( 10, add ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would have to be `int withFive(int x, int (*func)(int,int))`. However, using the raw function pointer syntax of C is quite unreadable. The recommended practice is to always use typedefs, like this:

```
typedef int operation_t (int x, int y); // function type acting as "template"

int add (int x, int y);
int withFive(int x, operation_t* op); // op is a pointer to function
...

withFive(10, add);
```